# How can I change extended latin characters to their unaccented ASCII equivalents?

Tags: regex, perl

I need a generic transliteration or substitution regex that will map extended latin characters to similar looking ASCII characters, and all other extended characters to '' (empty string) so that...

- é becomes e
- ê becomes e
- á becomes a
- ç becomes c
- Ď becomes D

and so on, but things like ‡ or Ω or ‰ just get striped away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All brilliant answers. But none actually really worked. Putting extended characters directly in the source-code caused problems when working in terminal windows or various code/text editors across platforms. I was able to try out Unicode::Normalize, Text::Unidecode and Text::Unaccent, but wan't able to get any of them to do exactly what I want.

In the end I just enumerated all the characters I wanted transliterated myself for UTF-8 (which is most frequent code page found in my input data).

I needed two extra substitutions to take care of æ and Æ which I want mapping to two characters

For interested parties the final code is: (the tr is a single line)

```
$word =~ tr/\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3\xC4\xC5\xC7\xC8\xC9\xCA\xCB\xCC\xCD\xCE\xCF
\xD0\xD1\xD2\xD3\xD4\xD5\xD6\xD8\xD9\xDA\xDB\xDC\xDD\xE0\xE1\xE2\xE3\xE4
\xE5\xE7\xE8\xE9\xEA\xEB\xEC\xED\xEE\xEF\xF0\xF1\xF2\xF3\xF4\xF5\xF6\xF8
\xF9\xFA\xFB\xFC\xFD\xFF/AAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoo
oooouuuuyy/;
$word =~ s/\xC6/AE/g;
$word =~ s/\xE6/ae/g;
$word =~ s/[^\x00-\x7F]+//g;
```

Since things like Ď are not part of UTF-8, they don't occur nearly so often in my input data. For non-UTF-8 input, I chose to just loose everything above 127.

Comment: I too am faced with a similar challenge and for the life of me cannot find a descent mapping table of extended characters to ascii http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443165/extended-characters-european-to-us-ascii-for-search-indexing

Answer (score 8):

Use Unicode::Normalize to get the NFD($str). In this form all the characters with diacritics will be turned into a base character followed by a combining diacritic character. Then simply remove all the non-ASCII characters.

Comment: That looks to be a useful suite of tools. Thanks. 
I just tried it on my sampled data. It failed to convert the strings as expected . Here's one example:

"Eugène Legout-Gérard" remains exactly the same under UTF-8 with or without the NFD transformation. I'm trying to get "Eugene Legout-Gerard"

Comment: Whether you print the normalized or form or the original doesn't make a difference. The difference is, though, that you can remove everything that is not ASCII from the normalized form which should give you what you want.

Comment: Actually NFD normalization won't get all the Latin characters with diacritics at all. The most common ones may be the Polish ł and the Danish/Norwegian ø. I'm not sure but possibly also the German ß.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) module might be of help?

[Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/Text-Unidecode-0.04/lib/Text/Unidecode.pm) looks promising, though it does not strip ‡ or Ω or ‰. Rather these are replaced by ++, O and %o. This might or might not be what you want.

[Text::Unaccent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Unaccent/Unaccent.pm), is another candidate but only for the part of getting rid of the accents.

Answer (score 2):

[Text::Unaccent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Unaccent) or alternatively [Text::Unaccent::PurePerl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Unaccent::PurePerl) sounds like what you're asking for, at least the first half of it.

```
$unaccented = unac_string($charset, $string);
```

Removing all non-ASCII characters would be a relatively simple.

```
s/[^\000-\177]+//g;
```

Answer (score 1):

When I would like translate some string, not only chars, I'm using this approach:

```
my %trans = (
  'é' => 'e',
  'ê' => 'e',
  'á' => 'a',
  'ç' => 'c',
  'Ď' => 'D',
  map +($_=>''), qw(‡ Ω ‰)
};

my $re = qr/${ \(join'|', map quotemeta, keys %trans)}/;

s/($re)/$trans{$1}/ge;
```

If you want some more complicated you can use functions instead string constants. With this approach you can do anything what you want. But for your case `tr` should be more effective:

```
tr/éêáçĎ/eeacD/;
tr/‡Ω‰//d;
```