# Extended characters (european) to US ascii for search indexing

Tags: java, search, full-text-search, solr, character

I'm looking for a table or heuristic library that can convert extended characters like the o with the hat above it to a regular ascii o.

I'm looking to do this for search indexing purposes since most people are not going to type the o with the hat.

For example I type "Cote" into the search but I want my search to include things like "Côte".

It appears Solr does not convert these.
I tried java.text.Normalizer and <strike>friends but that did not work.</strike> did work see solution below.

Comment: Looks like I might be able to take the first char in the code point as a heuristic: http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Comment: Damn it looks like I'm just going to have make a giant mapping table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) when performing your indexing and query analysis in Solr.  If you want this standalone you could just grab the source code and does whatever it does.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that filter. I'll have to replace my hack with this.

Answer (score 0):

I did some quick googling and really didn't come up with any available libraries that will do character translation.  I could be missing something though.

I did find the solr javadoc for all their factory classes:
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/analysis/package-summary.html

I'm sure you've seen the above already, but perhaps there is something there that you can use.

My personal suggestion is that you will have to write your filter.  Which I don't believe will be very easy.  If you accept only unicode, things will be easier, but if you're using a webapp, then you will have to be concerned about characterset coming in from your user's browser and then convert that characterset to unicode.

Best of luck.

Comment: I did but it looks like this is promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450026/how-can-i-change-extended-latin-characters-to-their-unaccented-ascii-equivalents

Answer (score 0):

This does appear to work:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;

Normalizer.normalize("ô", Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right general idea but the wrong specific approach.

Note, that in many European languages, it's a very bad idea to strip accents. People type them for a reason. Very different words differ only by an accent. 'papa' is not the same as 'papá'. Not even close. Users of these languages expect to type them in and expect to get search hits that respect the distinctions.

Second, there is plenty of existing work in this area. See lucene.apache.org, which has a set of token filters that do a variety of things you might or might not want.

There are also commercial offerings with other potentially useful behaviors, such as mapping 'running' to 'run' and all that.

If you are really sure you want to do this, first normalize to 'decomposed' (NFKD), and then  just remove the accents. Viol(å).

Comment: while I generally agree with you that in most cases I should represent the distinction better for this case I am dealing with mainly Americans search for products (see my site http://evocatus.com/) I'm indexing both spelling combinations. Most e-commerce sites like amazon even remove the characters in the presentation for products. I'm at least retaining the true spelling while widening the search but unfortunately providing more false positives.