# Perl Accented character to Normal Character

Tags: perl, non-ascii-characters

I Have a Set of Accented Character like

[image]

I have to convert all the Accented Character to normal Character.

If i give àáâãäåæ or ÀÁÂÃÄÅ it should come normal 'a' or 'A'.

Please give any suggestion.

Comment: @SzG: The question you linked is itself a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11058211/1030675

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Text::Unidecode](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::Unidecode). The unidecode() function will take those characters and return their ASCII translations. However, be careful with this module as there a few disclaimers/constraints.

Hope that helps!